# Matlab UIControl Units

Tags: matlab, screen-resolution, uicontrol

I am using uicontrol to create GUI Elements. Following is my Code

```
uicontrol('Style','pushbutton', 'String','Load data','Parent',hTabs(1),'Position',[250 825 80 20], 'Callback',@ButtonCallback);
```

Here the problem is when i am using Units normalized option the GUI element is disappearing from Screen. I want to use normalized so that GUI adjusts itself in different screen resolutions. Any idea on this would be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `Normalized` units you need to define the position between 0 and 1, with 0 being the bottom/left hand side and 1 being the total height/width of the containing object.

You are currently defining the position using numbers that are well out of this range. You can do two things.

- Switch the units to `normalized` in seperate function call (demonstrated below)
- Create the `uicontrol` with normalized units, but you'll have to calculate the proper position vector

Here are examples on how to do either

A simple solution is to create the `uicontrol` and then set the units to normalized in a separate call

```
u = uicontrol(...) %don't specify the units
set(u,'Units', 'Normalized'); % this solves your problem
```

If you want to get the position vector in normalized units

```
normPos = get(u, 'Position') % get the position in normal space
```

Then use these numbers to create the `uicontrol` with normalized units:

```
u = uicontrol(...,'Units','Normalized', 'Position', normPos);
```

Answer (score 1):

When using the  `'units','normalized'` option you must change your position vector. The figure reference system has coordinates between 0 and 1.

E.g.

```
uicontrol('Style','pushbutton',...
          'String','Load data',...
          'Parent',hTabs(1),...
          'units','normalized',...
          'Position',[0 0 0.1 0.1],...
          'Callback',@ButtonCallback);
```

gives you a button 10% of the height and width in the lower left corner of the parent panel.